# cast e.NewItems without knowing type until runtime

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

So I have like 6 collection changed event handlers and realized I need to get rid of this duplicate code. The only difference between them is the type in the Cast.

```
e.NewItems.Cast<MyClass>().ForEach(l => l = //stuff);
```

Since NewItems is an IList, I found a way to get type in the collection and I want to use that in the Cast.

```
var t = sender.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault().GetType();
```

The problem is that I cant use a variable in the type brackets <> of Cast. Any way I can do this or do something that accomplishes the same thing?

EDIT:

```
    private void Profiles_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                e.NewItems.Cast<Profile>().ForEach(l => PerformOperation(l, DatabaseOperation.Add, false));
                e.NewItems.Cast<Profile>().ForEach(l => l.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                e.OldItems.Cast<Profile>().ForEach(l => PerformOperation(l, DatabaseOperation.Remove, false));
                e.OldItems.Cast<Profile>().ForEach(l => l.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you provide two sample event handlers (including the method parameters `sender` and `e`) to help clarify the question.

Comment: I suggest you to create a base class for all those 6 classes so you can fix the root of this problem

Comment: added it above. These classes already have a base class that acts as a wrapper for INotifyPropertyChanged that could be used.

Comment: Machinarius's comment actually sparked an idea and allowed me to solve the problem. I used the base class.

Answer (score 1):

How about a generic function?

```
public void YourMethod (IList<T> yourList)
{
    yourList.ForEach(l => l = //stuff);
}
```

Comment: Could I implement ForEach in IList as an extension method?

Comment: ForEach() extension method is already available for IList<T>, you can use it. Don't need to implement.

Comment: In a linq styled fashion?

Comment: Yes, you are already using it `e.NewItems.Cast<MyClass>().ForEach(l => l = //stuff);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you could write an interface or base class. That way you can do:

```
e.NewItems.Cast<IMyClass>().ForEach(l => l //stuff);
```

or

```
e.NewItems.Cast<MyBaseClass>().ForEach(l => l //stuff);
```